# ejabberd: Manipulate bookmarks with ejabberdctl

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am currently writing shell code that pushes data from LDAP into ejabberd, concerning MUC rooms. The last step I need to do is add some MUC rooms to users' bookmarks so they are auto-joined in their clients. There does not seem to be a module for that like there is in Prosody.

So I assume I need to mnipulate the users' private XML storage, in particular the storage:bookmarks part. I can get all existing bookmarks with:

```
ejabberdctl private_get user host storage storage:bookmarks
```

Then, there is `ejabberdctl private_set`, but I do not really understand it. From what I get, it seems that I need to replace the entire `storage` element at once, with old and new entries merged together.

Is there another way to add `conference` sub-elements to the node, or add bookmarks in some other way?

I tried to use `private_set`, but it seems to break on spaces in the element string. I tried escaping them in all possible ways, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found out for sure that adding new conferences to bookmarks requires re-uploading the entire bookmark storage set. That means the correct way is using `private_get` as shown in the question, then modify the XML to add a new entry and then use `private_set` to re-upload all of it.

As to the issue with spaces: Erlang shell (that's what ejabberdctl is) needs another level of quoting with single quotes, so some XML would become `"'<storage xmlns="storage:bookmarks"><conference jid=…'"` and so on in a shell argument.

You can find a shell script that does this and much more with ejabberdctl here: https://www.teckids.org/gitweb/?p=verein.git;a=blob;f=sysadmin/scripts/teckids-ejmaint

Comment: The quoting aspect no longer appears to be true as of Ejabberd 18. The following command works properly:

`./ejabberdctl private_set user domain.com "<storage xmlns='storage:bookmarks'><conference jid='test@conference.domain.com' autojoin='true' name='test'><nick>nickname</nick></conference></storage>"`

Answer (score 0):

There are two standards for MUC bookmarks in XMPP. The old standard, XEP-0049, uses Private XML storage that can be modified with the `private_set` command. But the more recent standard is to store the bookmarks in PEP: XEP-0223

Dominik George's answer works for the old standard; for the new PEP method you can use:

```
sudo ./ejabberdctl send_stanza user@domain.tld user@domain.tld '
<iq type="set" id="asdf">
   <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
      <publish node="storage:bookmarks">
         <item id="current">
            <storage xmlns="storage:bookmarks">
               <conference jid="room@conference.domain.tld" autojoin="true" name="name">
                  <nick>nick</nick>
               </conference>
            </storage>
         </item>
      </publish>
      <publish-options>
         <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
            <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
               <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish-options</value>
            </field>
            <field var="pubsub#access_model">
               <value>whitelist</value>
            </field>
         </x>
      </publish-options>
   </pubsub>
</iq>
'
```

This command is also accessible using the REST API: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#send-stanza